# How does Getopt::Std handle spaces in arguments on the command line?

Tags: perl, getopt

I've been playing around with the [Getopt::Std](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Std.html) module and was wondering about arguments taking spaces.

I have this code atm: `getopts('dp:h', \%options);`

The problem is, that if the argument following the p flag contains a space, `getopts` stops processing the list right when it hits the space. Is there a way I can allow spaces in the arguments without having to wrap the arguments following the flag in quotes (-p "something something")?

I'm fine with quotes. I'm just curious. Thanks guys!

Comment: I think it would be fine, and probably easier if when the user enters the first part of the argument, I then prompt for the second afterward just to ignore any confusion completely. Thank you for the links guys.

Comment: @Matt: I misunderstood your question, so I deleted my (unhelpful) answer. I still recommend that you check out Getopt::Long, however: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt::Long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://aplawrence.com/Unix/perlgetopts.html), someone did a lot of experimenting ..

and [this page](http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/cgi-perl/perl-getopt-getoptions-050422/page1.html) indicates that Double Quotes " char(34) will work, if you have spaces embedded, thus implying that there is no other way ..